# Nginx map directive always uses "default" with http param

Tags: nginx

I'm using Nginx map directive in order to retrieve the value of an http param and put it into another variable that will be used to do a basic auth with an ldap server (using nginx-auth-ldap).
The problem is that, according to my debug log, my map always chooses the default value.
Here is my configuration:

```
http {
include       mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;
sendfile        on;

map $args $groupe_ldap { 
default "default_group";
include /opt/nginx/appli.conf;
}

ldap_server my_ldap_server {
url ldap://somehost:someport/ou=xxx,dc=yyy,....;
binddn "...";
binddn_passwd "...";
require group "cn=$groupe_ldap,...";
group_attribute member; 
group_attribute_is_dn on;
require valid_user;
}

server {
    error_log /opt/nginx/log/debug.log debug;
    listen       8243;
    server_name  myhost;
    more_clear_input_headers 'X-Forwarded-For';
    auth_ldap "Forbidden";
    auth_ldap_servers my_ldap_server;

 if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|OPTIONS|POST)$ ) {
      return 403;
  break;
    }
location ~ ^(/monitor(.*)) {
    if ($arg_appli = "") {
       return 403;
       break;}

rewrite ^/monitor.* /$arg_appli?;
    proxy_set_header Host myhost:myport;
    root html;
    index index.html;
    break;
    }
error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }
}}
```

My appli.conf contains:
`appli=1 ESB_SUPERADMIN;`

The problem is that I always get default_groupe instead of ESB_SUPERADMIN when using this url: http://myhost:myport/monitor?appli=1.

Is something wrong on my configuration?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Update: The config bellow works fine on OS X

Comment: Update: the same config works fine on OS X without nginx-auth-ldap. So two differences: either the Nginx version (I'm using 1.6.2 on OS X while this issue happens with 1.7.7 on RHEL 6) or the nginx-auth-ldap. I will update tomorrow after some tests at work.